# proof-theoretic proof of Craig's interpolation theorem

Tags: logic, proof-theory

I am approaching the Craig's interpolation theorem from a proof-theoretic point of view. In particular I am trying to give a proof of the statement using the sequent calculus (both in the intuitionistic and classical case), via induction on the complexity of the derivation. However I am stuck at the case in which the last rule of the derivation is an introduction of implication to the left.
Does anyone please know where I can take some inspiration? Some paper, article or book to consult? or of course, has anyone ever tackle this proof?

Comment: See Gaisi Takeuti, [Proof Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=Idl6K-W69NYC&pg=PA31) (2nd ed - 1987), page 31.

Comment: Thank you! However My problem is with the case implication-left :( the induction hypothesis doesn't fit well with what  is needed to be proved. I am starting thinking it is due to the form of the rules in the calculus which one can choose

Comment: See also Troelstra, Schwichtenberg: Basic Proof Theory (2nd ed - 2001). If I remember correctly there was a subtle and easy to be overlooked switch of sides for a part of the context in one premiss of the left implication rule.